# Convert.ToDecimal; - An unhandled exception

Tags: c#

Im getting this error when i debug my program

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     int newCount;
     int oldCount;

     private void timerGetData_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string u = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
         u = u.Substring(u.IndexOf("<span id=\"PCoins\" class=\"Pcoins\""));
         u = u.Substring(u.IndexOf(">") + 1);
         u = u.Substring(0, u.IndexOf("</span>"));
         textBoxCoins.Text = u;

         newCount = Convert.ToDecimal(u);
         if (newCount <= oldCount)
         {
             textBoxNewCount.Text = "WON";
             oldCount = newCount;
         }
         else
         {
             oldCount = newCount;
             textBoxNewCount.Text = "LOSS";
         }
         timerGetData.Stop();
     }
}
```

The debugging is stopping at ***newCount = Convert.ToDecimal(u);***

Can anyone help me?

Comment: And what is the value of `u` before `newCount = Convert.ToDecimal(u);`? Also, you'd better use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack to parse html. It is far less error-prone way, though a bit more heavy-weight.

Comment: My u string is = 840.2449 directly from the webpage.

Comment: What is you locale setting? Converting a string in a decimal requires the string to be of the correct format for your locale settings unless you specify a CultureInfo parameters

Comment: By the way newCount is an integer, and you try to assign a decimal. This should never compile. You couldn't have this code with the exception you tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously `u` does not have a value that can be converted to decimal. You must trace your code to see why.

And change your variable types to decimal:

```
 decimal newCount;
 decimal oldCount;
```

insetead of

```
 int newCount;
 int oldCount;
```

Comment: My u string is = 840.2449 directly from the webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to have a string representing a valid value for a decimal then you should consider the locale settings of your machine. The conversion requires the string to be in the correct format for your locale if you don't specify the CultureInfo parameter.

If your string is in the Invariant culture like `840.2449` and your locale setting wants a comma as decimal separator then you need to specify the culture info

```
decimal newCount = 0;
string test = "840.2449";
newCount = Convert.ToDecimal(test, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(newCount);
```

Of course your actual code never compiles because you cannot assign the return of Convert.ToDecimal to a variable of type integer. In my example I have changed the variable to the correct datatype.